# Android In App Billing: How to detect and control purchases?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am developing an app in which there is authentication which means I am able to manage users and store them in database. Now I have items to be purchased from inside the app (Which I am trying to implement using the new play billing library).

**What I tried:**

The first thing I tried is to listen to the purchase and when complete I save the user ID along with the item he/she paid for in the database. But this is not safe because if a user made an account and paid for all items then he/she might pass this account to other users so that they can use it and access the items for free.

**Another way:**

I don't know much about in app billing but from what I learned, in app purchases are tracked by the primary account on the device that the user logged in, so now if I used this logic to query for user purchases per their primary account using the google play console. Then also any user might pay and pass their primary account to other users to log in through and they can access the products for free.

**Problem:**

In both ways users will be able to buy and pass accounts to other users so they access stuff for free.

**Question:**

I want a possible way that forces every user to pay for the items without having to worry about users passing accounts to each other.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You could have it monitor the login connections to the database? If another person attempts to login on a different device then it can force the other to logout? Or you could have a 2-3 device login rule?

Comment: @NickB how could a 2-3 device login rule work? how to track a device if in android?

Comment: @NickB do you mean store device id in database for every user?

Comment: I am unsure of how you'd do it for android, but I reckon you could store some unique device id against an account. When a user calls your database to see if it's allowed access to a purchased item it can check against your device id and see if it's the same. If it's not the same then it logs out the existing saved ID and creates a new login record with the new device ID. This would mean your friend would always kick you out if you're sharing accounts. I am more used to web based than Android. FYI :D

Comment: @NickB thanks for this great suggestion.

Comment: Cheers, let me know how you get on as I will be going down this route myself very soon.